Wrong date in startup message
I have a server A that sends a syslog message to another server B's rsyslog daemon, whenever it (A) starts up. To that end, I included in the root's crontab a directive similar to:
@reboot logger -T -n [SERVERB_IPADDR] -P [SERVERB_PORT] "Server A $(date) started up"

This works, the message appears in Server B's rsyslog. (There has been a significant amount of configuration done on Server B to make it listen to this particular TCP port, but that is irrelevant here.) However, I noticed that the date is completely wrong. Today, the message was
Server A Thu 8 Aug 2024 16:51:50 CEST started up

To troubleshoot this, I rebooted Server A once more, and now the date was
Server A Thu 8 Aug 2024 16:51:54 CEST started up

Only 4 seconds off. Of course, manually running the logger command turns up the correct date. What goes wrong here? How can I troubleshoot this? Server A runs on a Raspberry Pi, could it be that the clock isn't completely initialized at the time cron is started?
Both servers run Ubuntu Server, A is on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, B is on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS.
EDIT: it turns out that the clock on this system is incorrect at the time the startup message is fired. Adding sleep 60 &&  in front of the logger command sends the message 60 seconds later, but with the correct timestamp, to the rsyslog server. Thanks to @terdon for the suggestion.
I consider this a bug: at reboot time, any commands entered in the crontab apparently cannot rely on the internal clock.

To get the obvious out of the way, is the date correctly configured on serverA? If you log in there normally and run date, is the output correct? You suspect it might be a timing issue, what happens if you make the cron run at a specific time instead of on reboot so you can be sure the machine has finished initializing?

@terdon Oh yes, this machine sends hundreds of log messages to Server B daily, each with correct time stamps. Only this startup message has the wrong date and time, subsequent logging is correct.

Then isn't that your answer? Have you tried using something like @reboot sleep 60 && logger -T ... to add a bit of delay? Maybe there's an NTP service involved and it takes a few seconds for the time to be synced from the remote NTP server?

@terdon Good idea. I'll edit my question.

It turns out that the clock is wrong at the time the log message is sent. There is a corresponding line in the local /var/log/syslog:
2024-08-08T16:52:01.461191+02:00 serverA systemd[1]: Started cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon.
(...)
2024-08-08T16:52:02.276312+02:00 serverA CRON[1005]: (root) CMD (logger -T.. etc.)

Notice the wrong date. This could be particular to this hardware (Raspberry Pi). So the lesson from this should be: don't rely on the system time in your @reboot commands in the crontab.
In fact, I have NTP running on this server. It starts up slightly earlier than cron. The clock then still indicates 8 August. NTP then sends out various calls to time servers. Half a second later, the clock has been set to the correct date, but by that time, cron has already sent out its logging message with the wrong time.

Nice! I wonder why, though. Is it NTP then? So the local clock is wrong but is corrected upon connection to the NTP server? If so, although I really don't know much about this at all, but maybe you could correct the local clock?

@terdon I'll add something about NTP to my answer.
